# Select rows from database by strlen

Tags: mysql, string, string-length

Is there a way to select database table rows where a given value is a certain length, for example, less than 5 chars long?

In PHP that would be [`strlen`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strlen.php).

Is there anything similar in MySQL?

Answer (score 79, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE CHAR_LENGTH(column_name) < 5
```

Comment: All MySQL String functions are over there : http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html -- Enjoy !

Comment: All programming books, algorithms, Math - are over there - http://google.com. Still enjoy this?

Comment: @ArthurKushman I think you inferred snarkiness where there was none to be found.

Answer (score 9):

`LENGTH("my_string")` Return the length of a string in bytes

```
SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE LENGTH(column_name) < 5
```

Keep in mind that characters can be made up of multiple bytes like those in UTF-8.

Comment: Which will fall over with multi-byte characters.

Comment: @Derek thank you, I added a clarification, my answer mentioned that it returns the length in bytes, and characters can be multi-byte.

Comment: Yes, but in the real world this is almost useless (without mb check).

Comment: @zeusakm That's why we have the other answer! Now we know both ways.